# Hive on Spark, and Spark using Hive metastore at the same time?

Tags: bigdata, data-science

I am testing Hive on Spark as engine, but I want at the same time, use Hive metastore to access schemas using Spark, but till now, every combination of versions I have tested have failed.
Could you please recommend to me one version of Spark and one version of Hive that I can use to achieve this? 
Thank you

Comment: What does `tested` mean?  Could you walk us through?

Comment: I want to install Spark 2.3.1(or at least 2.2.0,the version I have on production) with a version of Hive to read schemas in its metastore, but when I achieve it, then Hive on Spark as execution engine (hive.execution.engine=spark) is not working due to JavaSparkListener ERROR. In Spark source code there are restrictions on Hive (<code>0.12.0</code> through <code>2.1.1</code>). I can not have both at once? Thank you

Comment: Install a distro (e.g. latest HortonWorks HDP) where components have been aligned to work together. Building your own mix is hard...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953688/setting-spark-as-default-execution-engine-for-hive

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect Spark SQL to remote Hive metastore (via thrift protocol) with no hive-site.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31980584/how-to-connect-spark-sql-to-remote-hive-metastore-via-thrift-protocol-with-no)